# How to disable chome's "Search GitHub" feature?

Tags: git, google-chrome, github

[image: Chrome address bar image with github specific search]

Every time I start typing "git ...", the chrome search bar changes into a github specific search (check out above image link). Say I want to search "git commit hooks". Immediately after typing "git ", the address bar changes and search is now restricted to the github domain. That's not what I want.

How do I disable this?

I have looked at all of my extensions, and none of them seem to be causing it. The behaviour extends into the incognito mode. Is this a default chrome behaviour or is it some other software that I installed?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a 'custom search engine'.

Go in to *Settings*, *Search*, then *Manage search engines*, then scroll down to find and remove Github.

[image: screenshot of search engine settings dialog]

Note that in my config (which is default) the search is triggered by `github.com` not just `git` - so you could just set the hotword back to that and it would be less intrusive.

Comment: Thanks poolie. This is the first time I came to know about the custom search thingie. Surprisingly, nothing else seems to trigger this behaviour... like "amazon " or "ebay ".

Comment: @Jug in my config (which is default) the search is triggered by `github.com` not just `git` - so you could just set the hotword back to that and it would be less intrusive.